# Probability density of a product of two random variables (discrete and continuous)

Tags: probability, random-variables

If $X$ is a gaussian random variable with $\mu=0$ and $\sigma^2=1$, and $Y$ is a discrete random variable taking the values $\{ {1,-1} \}$ with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ each. Let $Z=XY$, how do I find the CDF and PDF of Z?

Edit: $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

I started by evaluting:

$F_Z(z)=P(Z\leqslant z)=P(XY\leqslant z)=P(X\leqslant\frac{z}{Y})=$
$=P(X\leqslant -z|Y=-1).P(Y=-1) + P(X\leqslant z|Y=1).P(Y=1)$

But I'm not sure about this last expression, it seems incorrect and I can't see where is the problem.

Comment: You are going to need additional assumptions on the conditional probability

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align}
F_Z(z)&=P(Z\leqslant z)\\&=P(XY\leqslant z)
\\&=P(XY \le z|Y=-1)P(Y=-1)+ P(XY \le z|Y=1)P(Y=1)\\
&=P(X \ge -z|Y=-1)P(Y=-1)+P(X \le z|Y=1)P(Y=1)
\end{align}

If you assume independence, we can further simplify things.

Be careful when you work with negative number and inequalities.

Comment: Then, can I conclude that $F_z(z) = \frac{F_X(z)-F_X(-z)}{2}$?

Comment: not really, note that $P(X \ge -z) = 1-P(X < -z)$, you need to add one at the numerator.

Comment: Right, my bad, thank you! :D